# How to check if headset is plugged in or not?

Tags: android

I have used below code to check that headset connected or not in onCreate Mehod.

But every time it gives me output of not connected.

```
AudioManager audio=(AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(audio.isWiredHeadsetOn()){
             Toast.makeText(this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
             Toast.makeText(this,"Not Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Anybody can tell what's wrong with above code.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

Add this permission in your menifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to register a bradcast event (ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG).

in intent.getIntExtra("state", 0); you can get if headset is connected.

Hope this helps.